# JULIA: What's Erro! Lagrange Polynomials function

Tags: function, julia, polynomials

```
function lg(X,Y,Xint)

  n = length(X)
  L = ones(1:n)  

  for k = collect(1:n) 

     L[k] = 1
     for c = collect(1:n)            
         if c!=k
             L[k] = (L[k]*( Xint - X[c] ))/( X[k] - X[c] )
         end
     end        
  end
   return sum(Y.*L)
 end
```

=========================

When Executed

LoadError: InexactError()
while loading In[76], in expression starting on line 1

in lg at In[74]:11?

Answer (score 3):

`ones` of a range creates an Int64 Array:

```
julia> o = ones(1:3)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 1

julia> o[1] = 3.5
ERROR: InexactError()
 in setindex!(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Float64, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:339
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:226
```

*You can't assign a Float64 into a Int64 Array (you get this error).*

You want to just use `ones(n)` to get a Float64 Array:

```
julia> ones(3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
```

---

Side note: You don't need to `collect` before iterating over a range:

```
for k = collect(1:n)
```

instead just iterate over the range:

```
for k = 1:n
```

Comment: Hi Andy
its now Works!

Comment: Thanks! ;) -----------------

Comment: Fantastic! Please do upvote and [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/184179) :)